# updating Table from Form data input using Spring MVC+JDBC

Tags: mysql, spring, model-view-controller, jdbc

I am having issue with updating records on a table using jdbcTemplate.

here is my jsp form

```
<form:form method="post" action="edit" modelAttribute="Student">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>id:</td>
            <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Salary:</td>
            <td><form:input path="salary" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Designation:</td>
            <td><form:input path="designation" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Update" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

update method in StudentDaoImpl class is:

```
 public void update(Student s) {

    String sql = "UPDATE Student set name=?, salary=?, designation=? where id=?";           
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql,s.getId(),s.getName(),s.getSalary(),s.getDesignation());

    System.out.println("-- Student list is Updated---" );

    int status =jdbcTemplate.update(sql);

    System.out.println("-------status---"+status);
}
```

controller method for updating is:

```
@RequestMapping(value =("/edit"), method= RequestMethod.POST)

public ModelAndView editStudent(@ModelAttribute("Student") Student student,BindingResult result, ModelMap map){

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/applicationContext.xml");
     StudentDAO dao = (StudentDAO) ac.getBean("studentDao");        

    // map.addAttribute("id", student.getId());
     map.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
     map.addAttribute("salary", student.getSalary());
     map.addAttribute("designation", student.getDesignation());

     dao.save(student);


return new ModelAndView("redirect:/viewstudent");

}
```

I want to update record by id on my student table...I get sql query error.
What I am doing wrong? please suggest.

Comment: try giving the id in the sql query as the last parameter in the update method.

Comment: i get this error:HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [UPDATE Student set name=?, salary=?, designation=? where id=?]; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, salary=?, designation=? where id=?' at line 1..

Comment: its working now the issue was:  int status =jdbcTemplate.update(sql);

Comment: Its working after your suggestions and correcting to  match to int status =jdbcTemplate.update(sql,s.getName(),s.getSalary(),s.getDesignation(),s.getId());

Comment: Good to know that it worked @javaz